# Why if one approximation is too big, the other turns out to be too small, and vice-versa?

Tags: approximation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

$\left|\dfrac{m^2}{n^2}-2\right|$ with $\left|\dfrac{(m+2n)^2}{(m+n)^2}-2\right|$. We need to take absolute values, because if one approximation is too big, the other turns out to be too small, and vice-versa.

Comment: Is this for arbitrary $m$ and $n$ positive inters?

Comment: Yes, this is for arbitrary positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

This amounts to checking that if $m^2<2n^2$, then 
$$(m+2n)^2>2(m+n)^2 \tag1$$
and similarly for the reverse inequalities.

You just have to expand $(1)$:
$$\not m^2+\not4\not m\not n+\not4_{\textstyle2}n^2>\not2m^2+\not4\not m\not n+\not2\not n^2\iff 2n^2>m^2.$$

Comment: Hmm...I  see now but how did you set it up like that (it makes complete sense). I just started with math and I am annoyed that I cant figure these on my own.I feel like I am not learning anything if everyone just answer for me.

Comment: I just translated it  into inequalities on integers and simplified. I think it's rather natural  to transform a question on rational numbers into a question on integers. That said, it's also a matter of training. The more exercises you solve (of different types, or with different methods), the more you can imagine a solution/method for a new exercise.